# ButterKnife.bind with super class

Tags: java, android

I am using `ButterKnife` in my project, and as we know we have to write `ButterKnife.bind(this);` in all the activities, so I have just created `BaseActivity` like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, int layout) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
}
```

and I am calling it from other activity like this

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.txtName)
    TextView txtName;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.activity_splash);
    }
}
```

I want to know whether it is good practice to follow this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Override `setContentView` instead of a different `onCreate` that receives the layout id.

```
public class BaseActivity {

    protected void setContentView(Int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

}
```

Overriding this makes it more consistent (no custom onCreate) with the android style, I think.

I dont see any problem of using it, its cool since everytime you create a new activity its already there so just add @BindView and it works.

Other alternative is not using ButterKnife but Kotlin and Kotlin Extensions, take a look.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: I have created `BaseActivity` for many purposes, but i just want to know whether its good practice to write `ButterKnife,bind()` in `BaseActivity`, so that i can omit writing that line in all other activities

Comment: @RaviRupareliya check the updated answer